# Angular 9 - router-outlet for children layout components and page content

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I'm developing an App where I need different page layouts depending on the route I'm currently in.
In particular I have a BaseLayout component where I want to load other different layout components and then load the content of the page. Here's an example:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #snav mode="'over'" fixedInViewport [fixedTopGap]="isXSmall ? 56 : 64">
     // Sidenav content
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
     // load this components depending on route
     <app-toolbar></app-toolbar> // load toolbar depending on route
     <app-header></app-header> // load header depending on route
     <app-content></app-content> // contains a router-outlet where I want to display page content
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

So for example: when I navigate to /home I want this layout where only the toolbar and content shows.
Here's my app.route:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: BaseLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/pages/home/home.module').then(m => HomeModule)
  }
]
```

And here's my home.routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

My problem is on loading dynamically the single layout parts of the BaseLayout. I'm not sure what should be the optimal routes configuration.

**EDIT:**
This is what I tried:
app.routes:

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: BaseLayoutComponent,
    children: [
    {
       path: '',
       component: ToolbarComponent,
       outlet: 'toolbar'
    },
    {
       path: '',
       component: HeaderComponent,
       outlet: 'header'
    },
    {
       path: '',
       loadChildren: () => import('./main/pages/home/home.module').then(m => HomeModule)
  }
]
```

}

And in my BaseLayoutComponent html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #snav mode="'over'" fixedInViewport [fixedTopGap]="isXSmall ? 56 : 64">
     Sidenav content
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
      <router-outlet name="toolbar"></router-outlet>
      <router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
      <app-content></app-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This works, but again I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: I don't undrestand your question, when you say different layout based on route, can you provide examples of different layout? creating stackblitz will be helping.

Also I notice you dount have any router-outlet in your components

Comment: For example with or without the app-header component. I edited the question, you should see 2 router-outlets and in app-component there's one more for the actual content of the page